# My new Nikon d3500 is not showing the light meter in live view mode

Tags: nikon, metering

All the tutorials are saying the light meter (exposure meter) in live view mode  should be there, except that it's not showing there in my brand new camera, lol. Is there a setting I might have set that could be preventing me from seeing it in live view mode?

Comment: See https://www.dummies.com/photography/cameras/nikon-camera/how-to-check-the-exposure-meter-on-your-nikon-d5300/

Comment: Thanks but I've already seen this guide, it says here "M mode: The meter is always present in the Information and Live View displays and also appears in the viewfinder data display." My meter just does not appear in the live view display in M mode - my whole problem in the first place. Any ideas why? I wish I could add a photo of it here, in M mode and live view mode with no exposure meter, real pain to keep having to leave the live view mode to be able to see the light meter.

Answer (score 2):

If you press the info button when in live view it cycles what info shows up. Cycle through and it should show up on one of the screens.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to find out if it is a setting problem or a flaw in the camera would be to reset all options:

Shooting Menu Options | Reset Shooting Menu | Setup Menu Options | Reset all options (at the end of the menu list). That keeps your language, date, and time zone settings but puts everything else back to the factory default. You'll know then if it's something you changed or not.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an incompatible lens attached, the exposure meter on the D3500  will not appear.

This is poor UI design, and it's not mentioned in the manual.

But I just tested this with a D3500, and when using an older lens (that takes pictures just fine), the camera doesn't show the exposure meter. When using the kit lens that came with the camera, the camera *does* show the meter.

So if the meter drops off the face of the earth, try a different lens.